# Origin of the word "trombone" in the sense of "paperclip"

Tags: usage, étymologie

With school around the corner, I got a package of paperclips and I notice the French translation for *paperclip* is the word *trombone*. What does this have to do with the instrument? They look quite similar to me, *paperclips* and *trombones*. Is this just slang or official? Which came first?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [CNRTL's etymology's page](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/trombone), the name comes from the instrument

> 1949, par analalogie de forme : « petite agrafe servant à réunir des papiers »

it is official, and as far as I know there is no exact synonym.

Comment: Even though it's an official and proper word, I do think they both come from the same source : Elephants!    I'm serious by the way. The elephants trump, or trompe in french, is often all curled up, like the shape of a trumpet, a trombone or a... trombone.

Comment: I think you mean "trunk" in English, lol

Answer (score 5):

Ce n'est pas le sujet principal de la question, mais ma curiosité m'a fait chercher l'étymologie du nom de l'instrument lui-même, qui est assez simple : de l'italien *trombone*, qui est lui-même l'augmentatif de *tromba* (trompette), qui subsiste en italien moderne.

Answer (score 5):

D'après le [CNRTL cité ci-dessus](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/trombone), il semble intéressant de noter que le nom "trombone" n'entre dans la langue que plus de 50 ans après son invention, du moins celle qui permettra de le nommer d'après l'analogie de forme, puisqu'il y en a eu [quelques autres](http://www.earlyofficemuseum.com/paper_clips.htm).

À ma connaissance, et d'après ce qu'on peut constater sur les traductions proposées par la [page Wikipédia qui lui est consacrée](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombone_%28papeterie%29), il n'y a qu'en français que cet ustensile a été rapproché à l'instrument de musique.

Néanmoins, il a subi une ellipse lexicale puisqu'il était à l'origine appelé une "attache trombone".